# How to check if Class<Object> is castable to class

Tags: java

How can I check if `Class<Object>` stores class that can be casted to another class, e.g. `String`? I tried to use `clazz.isInstance(String.class)`, but this check always return true, because e.g. String is instance of Object.

Note that I cant use `instanceof`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`isAssignableFrom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-)

A String is an Object but an Object is not necessarily a String. So Object is assignable from String, but not the other way around.

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Object.class.isAssignableFrom(String.class)); //true
        System.out.println(String.class.isAssignableFrom(Object.class)); //false
    }
}
```